# How to make span the same size as its children?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place the logo and the form on the same line but can't because the span that containing the logo is spanning the whole line. How do I make it the same size as its content?

```css
header {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #333333;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

.clear {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.LogoHeader {
  height: 25%;
  width: 25%;
  border-spacing: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 47px;
}

.SearchForm {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.SearchField {
  display: inline;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 20px;
  object-position: right;
  margin: 0px 10px white;
}

.SearchButton {
  display: inline;
  background-color: deeppink;
  border-style: none;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <span style="position:relative;float: right; clear: right; width: 100%;"><a href="#website" class="clear"><img class="LogoHeader" src="C:\Users\David\Desktop\WebDevelopmentTest\images\NotWalla\logo.svg" alt="My news website"></a></span>
  <div style="position: relative; vertical-align: middle; right: 50%; display: inline-block; height: -50%">
                <form class="SearchForm">
                    <input class="SearchButton" type="submit" value="Search"><input class="SearchField" type="text" name="q" value autocomplete="off">
                </form>
        </div>
</header>
```

Comment: First of all: Do not put form in span, that is invalid HTML.

Comment: your code is invalid, replace `<span>` with some suitable element like `<div>`

Comment: What exactly are you aiming for? If you remove the wrapping `span` and `div`, the logo is on the left and the search is to its right, on the same line...

Comment: I'm trying make the search bar and buyton be on the same line as the logo and also make the logo resizeable as i resize the window

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `width: 100%;` from span styles.

Comment: I tried that but then the logo becomes very small and I tried to fix it myself but wasn't able to, so I figured changing the span would be much easier

Comment: It is because your logo size is related to its parent. `width: 25%;` . Set a fixed size for it, Or set a `min-width: 100px` for example, and `min-height: ??px` for it.

Comment: Could you demonsrate what you mean by that? I.e. implament it in the code

Comment: Your logo get very small when you removed the span width: 100%. To avoid this you can set a `min-height` and `min-width` style for your logo. For example if you want the width of your logo is at least 150px, do this: `.LogoHeader{ min-width: 150px; }`

Answer (score 0):

Well... After some messing around I was able to figure it out!
You can't really see it in the code below but it definitely works.
Thank you all for the help.

```css
  header {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #333333;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

.clear {
  display: inline;
  min-height: 28px;
}

.LogoHeader {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.SearchForm {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.SearchField {
  border: none;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0px 10px white;
  direction: rtl;
}

.SearchButton {
  background-color: deeppink;
  border-style: none;
  line-height: 30px;
```

```html
<header style=" border-bottom: 20px solid #333; border-top: 20px solid #333;">
  <div style=" width: 100%; float: right; clear: both; max-width: 303px; margin-right: 10px; transform: translateY(-6px)">
    <a href="#website" class="clear"><img class="LogoHeader" src="C:\Users\David\Desktop\WebDevelopmentTest\images\NotWalla\logo.svg" alt="My news website"></a>
  </div>
  <form class="SearchForm">
    <input class="SearchButton" type="submit" value="Search"><input class="SearchField" type="text" name="q" value autocomplete="off">
  </form>
</header>
```